# required attribute not working when form.submit is used

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the html5 required attribute to check if mandatory fields are being filled in by the user or not. Every thing seems to be working fine as long as i use a submit button. But when i change the submit button to be a normal button and then call a JavaScript function with the onClick event so that some verification is done in javascript and then i use document.form.formname.submit() to submit the form. But when i do this, The required fields are not being checked whether they are empty or not. I am using Chrome 11.0
Here is the html code:

```
<form method="post" action="./post_discussion.php" name="newdiscussion">
<span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Title: </span>

<input id="title_text" name="title_text" style="width:650px; margin-left:10px;" type="text" placeholder="Whats the title of your discussion? Be clear." required="required" />
<br/><br/>
<div style="margin-top:10px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Make your point</div>

<textarea id="text_area" name="text_area" style=" height:200px; margin-top:10px;" placeholder="Describe your point of discussion. Be clear on the point and provide convincing
 evidence.A claim without evidance will not be encouraged by the site." cols="90" required="required"/>
</textarea><br />

<div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:5px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Tags</div>
<input id="tags_textfield" onkeyup="tags_generator()" name="tags_textfield" type="text" style="width:500px;" placeholder="Enter atleast one tag" onblur="clear_tags()" autocomplete="off" required="required"/>

<ul id="tags_ul"><div id="tag_drop_down"></div></ul><br/>

<div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:5px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Users involved</div>
<input id="uids_textfield" name="uids_textfield" type="text" style="width:500px;" placeholder="Enter all the users involved" required="required"/>
<br/>

<?php
 if(!isset($_COOKIE["username"]))
 {
     echo '<div id="comment">You are not signed in. Please enter your credintials to post the discussion.</div><br/>';
    echo 'Username: <input id="bottom_username" type="text" name="username"/><br/> 
       Password: <input id="bottom_password" name="password" type="password"/>';
    echo   '<br/><br/>
<input id="post_button" onclick="new_discussion(0)" type="button" value="Post the discussion" style="margin-top:10px;"/>';
 }
 else
 echo   '<br/><br/>
<input id="post_button" type="button" onclick="new_discussion(1)" value="Post the discussion" style="margin-top:10px;"/>';
?>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function new_discussion(arg)
{
    if(arg==1)
    {

        document.forms.newdiscussion.submit();
    }
    else
    {
        //some logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a normal button as submit button? A normal button isn't linked with the form, the browser don't check the required attributes of the input fields!

Comment: @ChristianB as you can see, when the cookies are not set, i ask for a user credentials and want to validate the submitted credentials using ajax(not shown here). Other wise the form gets submitted normally.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that you are testing it on a browser that supports "required": http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

> The required attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome.
>
> **Note:** The required attribute of the  tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Use submit buttons and give them two different id's, maybe *loginSubmit* and *submit*. Catch out the click on this two submit buttons and check, which id is in DOM tree:

```
if(document.getElementById('submit') != undefined) {
    // start new discussion
    ...
} else {
    // do login and start new discussion
    ...
}
```

Comment: the reason why i avoided the submit buttons is, when the login fails due to invalid credentials, i want all the fields in the page to retain their values. So i am validating the user credentials using ajax. If both are used as submit buttons then i will have to loose the values in text fields in case user login fails.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried instead of:

```
<input id="uids_textfield" name="uids_textfield" type="text" style="width:500px;" placeholder="Enter all the users involved" required="required"/>
```

this:

```
<input id="uids_textfield" name="uids_textfield" type="text" style="width:500px;" placeholder="Enter all the users involved" required />
```

Note that instead of putting `required="required"` I used `required`

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 validation only works on form submit.  You'll need to do this at the end of your JavaScript validation:

```
document.newdiscussion.submit();
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onsubmit` attribute in form tag:

```
<html:form styleId="myForm" action="/login" onsubmit="return demo()">
```

and button:

```
<input type="submit" value="login" />
```

and function:

```
function demo() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); 
}
```